# Hibernate query : retrieve rows from the many side matching with one side

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have an issue while retrieving records from the database using hibernate. This is the situation.
I have 3 classes (and 3 tables as well).

These are my classes.

```
Exam
-----
Integer exam_id
String exam_name

Subject
-------
Integer subject_id,
String subject_name

Scores
-------
Exam exam,
Subject subject,
Integer score
```

These are my tables

```
Exam
-----
exam_id,
exam_name

Subject
-------
subject_id,
subject_name

Scores
-------
exam_id,
subject_id,
score
```

What I want to do is , I want to retrieve all the scores for the science subject. I think can do this using this sql query.

select sc.* from Scores sc inner join subject su on sc.subject_id=su.subject_id where su.subject_name= "science".

But I want to know the best way to archive this. Is it possible to do this using "criteria"? or any other best way? Please guide me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can using criteria, but is more simple using a simple HQL query.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();   //em is the entity manager

CriteriaQuery<Scores> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery(Scores.class);             
Root<Scores> scoreRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Scores.class);

Subquery<Integer> subquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Integer.class);
Root root = subquery.from(Subject.class);

subquery.select(root.get("subject_id"));
subquery.where(cb.equal(root.get("subject_name"), "science"));

criteriaQuery.where(cb.equal(scoreRoot.get("subject_id"),subquery));

TypedQuery<Score> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

return query.getResultList(); //this is the result
```

This is using criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is an ORM technology. If you have such PK/FK related tables, you should tell Hibernate about them by XML configuration or annotation based mapping. Then you can get your result by an HQL query something like this;

```
from Scores sc where sc.subject.subjectName="science"
```

I assume Scores table and Subject table are related by subject_id column. So, your classes should be like this;

```
class Scores{
  Subject subject;
  Exam exam;
  int score;

  // getters and setters
}

class Subject{
  int subjectId;
  String subjectName;

 // getters and setters
}

class Exam{
  int examId;
  String examName;

 // getters and setters
}
```

Then you can reach the scores by using subject field of Scores object.